# Function within setTimeout variable being overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a function that is within a loop. I have a `setTimeout` function around this function. My problem is that a variable which is being set is then getting overwritten because of the setTimeout (this needs to stay). Is there a simple way to fix this issue?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/L29yk2o6/

```
$("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
    $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        myFunct($this);
    }, i*100);
});

function myFunct (item)
{
    var myText = item.text();
    $('body').prepend('<p>'+myText+'</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what happens when you forget to use `var` and create a global variable.

```
$this = $(this);
```

needs to be

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: Can't believe i missed this. I need a coffee, Thanks.